# Migrating GetTargetsByCampaignIdsRequest and GetTargetsByCampaignIds to Bing Ads v11

Tags: php, bing-ads-api

As we migrate to Bing Ads API v11 using PHP SDK, we are currently stuck with Targets specifically the `GetTargetsByCampaignIdsRequest` and `GetTargetsByCampaignIds` which was supported by `CampaignManagementService` earlier in v10.

We tried to use v10 classes but that didn't work as the `GetTargetsByCampaignIds` itself has been removed.

We did browse through the confusing migration documents and didn't find anything that explained us how to fetch `CampaignCriterion` for all campaigns. Has anyone found a work around for this?

**Our existing code to pull all `Targets` for further checks and ad pausing:**

```
$request = new GetTargetsByCampaignIdsRequest();
$request->CampaignIds = $campaignIds;
$campaignTargets = $this->campaignManagementServiceProxy->GetService()->GetTargetsByCampaignIds($request);
```

**Note:** Will update the question if I find anything new from the docs/forum.